# Laravel PUT Request

Tags: laravel

I have a problem when i am trying to update in my table
it wont updated and return
data []

[image]

Function update in Controller

```
public function update(StorePersonRequest $request, Person $person)
    {
        $person->update($request->all());

        return new PersonResource($person);

    }
```

StorePersonRequest :

```
class StorePersonRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'CoPe'=>'required',
            'NaPe'=>'required',
            'PhoPe1'=>'required',
            'Corq'=>'required',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Choose PUT method in POSTMAN instead of POST

Comment: it tell me "message": "The CoPe field is required. (and 3 more errors)",

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Could you please show what it is showing in `dd($request->all())`

Comment: i tried to change "post " to PUT but it's not working so when i pass to postman 
_method -> PUT return data[]

Comment: @SarojShrestha it return an array

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you check whether `update` is called after all? Whether it does what it should? You could use XDebug to check this

Comment: Nothing iam new in laravel and i am learning how to deal with API

Comment: @OscarDiaz Could you show it. Also, on model is it fillable?

Comment: `class Person extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'CoPe',
        'NaPe',
        'JoPe',
        'TelPe',
        'FaxPe',
        'PhoPe1',
        'PhoPe2',
        'PlPe',
        'NotPe',
        'EmPe',
        'DaNpe',
        'Corq',
        'FaPe',
        'MaPe',
        'BirthPe',
        'NoNuPe',
        'NoNu1Pe',
        'CfPe',
        'TyPe',
        'GePe',
        'Creator',
        'AttPe',
        'Co',
        'AttF',
        'AttL'
    ];
}`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't add source code to the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Did Solve it
this is my code in controller file

```
public function update(StorePersonRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $input = Person::find($id); 
        $input->CoPe = $request->get('CoPe');
        $input->NaPe = $request->get('NaPe');
        $input->JoPe = $request->get('JoPe');
        $input->TelPe = $request->get('TelPe');
        $input->FaxPe = $request->get('FaxPe');
        $input->PhoPe1 = $request->get('PhoPe1');
        $input->PhoPe2 = $request->get('PhoPe2');
        $input->PlPe = $request->get('PlPe');
        $input->NotPe = $request->get('NotPe');
        $input->EmPe = $request->get('EmPe');
        $input->DaNPe = $request->get('DaNPe');
        $input->Corq = $request->get('Corq');
        $input->FaPe = $request->get('FaPe');
        $input->MaPe = $request->get('MaPe');
        $input->BirthPe = $request->get('BirthPe');
        $input->NoNuPe = $request->get('NoNuPe');
        $input->NoNu1Pe = $request->get('NoNu1Pe');
        $input->CfPe = $request->get('CfPe');
        $input->TyPe = $request->get('TyPe');
        $input->GePe = $request->get('GePe');
        $input->Creator = $request->get('Creator');
        $input->AttPe = $request->get('AttPe');
        $input->Co = $request->get('Co');
        $input->AttF = $request->get('AttF');
        $input->AttL = $request->get('AttL');
        $input->save();
        return response()->json([
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "updated successfully.",
        "data" => $input
    ]);
    }
```

Comment: You can also try to use mass-assignment and mass-update, using create(), update() and $fillable. Most of the time, it makes your life easier. Check it out: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same issue with postman. The problem is not on laravel but on the headers of your request. Select the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for headers and your body will be sent successfully.

Also in the method at the top select PUT instead of POST and remove the `_method` field of your body

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are not passing any file or something, I am not sure whether its good practice to use **form-data**. You could have just used **raw** and pass a json with your data using PUT OR PATCH. Also I see that you are passing an id also, any reason for that?

Anyway, I think that all you have to do to make it works, is to put the _method on your url. So in your case it should be like this:

```
localhost:8000/api/pe/2?_method=PATCH
```

(or PUT if you prefer it). Right now you are not passing it as a parameter, you include it in your body request. I believe that this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the route built out in the route folder? Either api.php or web.php like below?

```
Route::get('tasks', 'App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@index'); //get tasks with authenticated user_id where is_last_status is 0 with     
    Route::get('tasks/user/{user_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@tasksForUser'); //get tasks for specific user_id 
    Route::get('tasks/{task}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@show'); //get tasks with specified task id number in {task}
    Route::put('tasks/{task}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@update');
    Route::post('tasks','App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@store');
    Route::delete('tasks/{task}', 'App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@destroy');
```